# MySQL regexp behaviour

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table access_rules with a column path.
I added a row in the table:

```
INSERT INTO access_rules (path) VALUES ('/user/search/*'), ('/user'), ('/someotherpath')
```

Now, I executed a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `access_rules` where '/user/search/ddd' regexp path
```

I wanted to return /user/search/*, but the query returns both `'/user/search/*'` and `'/user'`.
Can anybody tell me why is it like that?

Comment: I think if you had `/search` in `path`, it'd have returned as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/user` is the same as `^.*/useruser.*$`.  That is *anything* can exist before or after `/user` for there to be a match.

Meanwhile, `/user/search/*` matches `/user/search/////` and `/user/search`.  Probably not what you wanted.  You probably wanted `.*` instead of `*`.

Since you seem to have only 'prefix' matching, I suggest you change to

```
WHERE '...' LIKE CONCAT(path, '%')
```

If `/user` is supposed to be an 'exact' match, then that won't work.  In which case, switch to

```
INSERT INTO access_rules (path)
    VALUES ('/user/search/%'),  -- note the change here
           ('/user'),
           ('/someotherpath')
SELECT * FROM `access_rules` where '/user/search/ddd'
     LIKE path   -- note LIKE, not REGEXP
```

Comment: Caveat:  I did not check that code; hopefully it will give you sufficient ideas.

Comment: Actually SELECT * FROM `access_rules` where '/user/search/ddd'  LIKE path is what I wanted, thanks